# Golf V 1.9 TDI 77kw 2005 year wont start

Tags: vw, golf

I have a Golf V 1.9 TDI 77kw year 2005.

Last week during driving suddenly the motor got detached, one of the bolts holding it was worn out.

I went to the mechanic and he reattached the motor and said that there were no issues.

After getting my car back I drove it across town and there were no issues, then I needed to go to another city and drive on the highway and after driving for about 60km the car suddenly stopped working, I was going 120km/h and suddenly the gas stopped working and after 2 seconds the battery light went on. I exited the road with the speed that the car had and then I tried starting it about 20 times but no luck. It starts briefly for 1-2 seconds and then it turns off.

I took it back to the mechanic and he clearly has no idea what is happening with the car because his assumption is that the turbine is broke. I don’t buy that because I had that problem 4 years ago and I needed to repair the turbine. The car did not have an issue to start when the turbine was broken, it just was not able to go more than 90km/h and was wasting the oil down the exhaust and had a strange noise when pressing on the gas pedal.

Does someone have an idea what the issue might be? It is not the battery and it does not show any issues on the computer diagnostics tool.

Answer (score 1):

You car has an initial low pressure fuel pump which resides in the tank. It then uses a cam lobe (I believe) against the injector to create the high pressure fuel source it needs to actually inject fuel into the cylinder. If the low pressure pump goes out, it can cause the problem you are describing. The fuel pump may have enough umph to push a bit of fuel to the injectors at first, but not enough to keep the engine running for any length of time. You should be able to check the fuel pump pressure at the fuel rail ... at least I would think you could do this on a VW.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended being the turbine, it was clogged too much and no air could pass through it, leading into the car not starting, after repairing it the problem was fixed.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. Would be great if you could also flesh it out a bit -- any ideas about the cause of the turbo failure or symptoms leading up to it. I'm not sure that I see a causal connection between the engine mount failure and the turbo failure. It could be that you've been building up gunk in the intake system for quite a while and some of it got dislodged enough to block the turbo when the engine mount failed.

Answer (score 0):

When a MK5 TDI is driving normally but suddenly stalls while in motion and can not be re-started, Relay 460 is the most common cause. It often happens that the relay fails when you hit a minor bump in the road. (Why? Because VW.)

On your TDI, the engine controller is supplied with power through Relay 460, so if the relay fails the engine will not run. You will find this relay in the driver's side foot well behind a panel. There is a large 460 printed on the relay. You can pull it out from its socket by hand.

If you understand relays, you can remove Relay 460 and test it. Otherwise, you can take a chance and replace it; it's not expensive. If this does not repair your car, it has cost only a little, and the good news is that you now have a spare Relay 460 to keep in the car, because if you keep the car long enough, some day you will need it.

Comment: This will not normally show in a computer diagnostic of the car, right?

Comment: @JordanJordanovski There is no code for "Relay 460 malfunction". On my own MK4 TDI with different relays, I did not bother to read codes. When I hit a bump and the engine quit while I was driving, I pulled off the road and replaced Relay 109, which I kept in the car as a spare. Bingo, repair complete and I continued my trip. You can test the relay before replacing. Even if you just remove it, drop on a hard surface and re-install it, it might work temporarily until you can get a replacement. The internal contacts become worn and burned with age, and a hard impact can be a temporary fix.